# Overloading << operator to store data

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

First of, I've been searching all around for my particular problem but I havent' been able to find any answers.
So, what I want to do is to overload the `<<` operator so that I could do:

```
myObj = new MyObj();
unsigned int v = 2; 
myObj << v;
```

Keeping in mind that this would make that, using this class:

```
class MyObj{
private:
  char *data;
  int count;

public:
  MyObj(){ data = new char[64]; count = 0; }
  //This "is" the overloaded << method
  template <typename T>
  T& operator<<(T val){
    *(T*)(data + count) = val;
    count += sizeof(T);
  }
}
```

The effect should be the same as this (suppossing *data* is a public attribute):

```
myObj << v;
```

Should be the same as

```
*(unsigned int*)(myObj.data + myObj.count) = v;
myObj.count += sizeof(v);
```

Any ideas on how to do it? I have only find ways to overload the I/O or bit operators, but anything like this.

Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry. The title should be "<<" not ">>". I do want to overload >> also, but it's not what I intended to post.

Comment: You should be able to edit your question using the links below the tags. Anyway, I'm not a C++ person, but isn't it `operator<<`, not `overload<<`?

Comment: It is called operator<<(T val)

Comment: To be exact, it's mostly called `T & operator << (T & val)`.

Comment: And what is your problem? Are you worried about undefined behaviour, overflowing your buffer, not knowing the right type to unmarshall or something else? Because `operator>>` is basically overloaded the same way as `operator<<` is.

Comment: ah yes I'm sorry. I did it from memory and I made a few mistakes. Sorry again, I'll edit it now

Comment: My problem is how would I do that overload so that it works like
**myObj << dataVar;**
(edited)

Comment: Shouldn't this: `*(T*)(val + count) = val` be `*(T*)(data + count) = val`?

Comment: You should rarely use `new` in C++, and naked pointers even more rarely. I have a feeling that your design is generally somewhat flawed.

Comment: @fontanini yes it should, typo

Comment: @KerrekSB It's part of a networking application so I am dynamically casting data into a buffer as to send it over TCP as a byte (uint8) array

Comment: Edit: I said nothing here.. sry

Comment: The cast gymnastics that you are performing are undefined behaviour, by the way.

Comment: Undefined behavior why? As long as only basic types are used and count doesn't overflow I don't think any unexpected behavior is going to happen. As I said in the answer below, I don't need it to be reliable but fast, and I believe pointer casting that is the faster way, though I may well be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have

```
MyObj *myObj;
......
myObj = new MyObj();
unsigned int v = 2; 
myObj << v;
```

To be able to use `<<` like that, you usually have:

```
MyObj myObj;
......
unsigned int v = 2; 
myObj << v;
```

or you could use:

```
myObj = new MyObj();
unsigned int v = 2;
(*myObj) << v;
```

If you want to be able to write code like `myObj << u << v`, you further need:

```
....
    template <typename T>
    MyObj& operator<<(T val){
        *(T*)(data + count) = val;
        count += sizeof(T);
        return *this;
    }
....
```

Comment: Though I had already solved it I lacked that last piece. Thank you very much!

Comment: +1 but note that `*(T*)(data + count) = val;` only works with POD types… and should be an explicit `reinterpret_cast`… and this task would be better accomplished with specializations of `std::num_get` and `std::num_put` and more conventional `operator<<` overloads per serializable class.

Comment: As for POD that's not a problem, I'm just working with basic types. I know the way I do it's quite 'hacky' and not the most secure one. But given the situation an the use it's going to have, I need it to be fast not reliable, I'll leave it as it is. I will however take a look at you advice for further documenting and future projects. Thank you